# Pre-cache UIView's animation?

Tags: iphone, uiviewanimation, performance

I've set up a UIViewController that holds two other controllers:

```
MainVC -> SubVC1
       -> SubVC2
```

At start, I show the SubVC1's view. The user can then switch to SubVC2's view:

```
- (void)showOtherSide:(id)sender
{
   UIView *currentView = [self.view.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
   BOOL flipToRight;
   UIView *newView;
   if (currentView == subVC1.view)
   {
       newView = subVC2.view;
       flipToRight = YES;
   }
   else
   {
       newView = subVC1.view;
       flipToRight = NO;
   }

   [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
   [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
   [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
   if (flipToRight)
   {
       [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:currentView cache:YES];
   }
   else
   {
       [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:currentView cache:YES];
   }

   [currentView removeFromSuperview];
   [self.view addSubview:newView];
   [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

The problem now is that even in the simulator the first back and forth flips don't show up, instead the user sees the new view immediately. Because I set the animation caching to YES, the following flips show the animation (at least most of the time!).
I tried to put the animation code in the viewDidAppear: method too, but without any improvement.

Are there any good practices to pre-cache the animations?

Comment: What i got by this is you want to perform animation after a delay when view loads? Is it?

Comment: @rishi: The user can click on a button. Then the two views should be exchanged, visualized by a flipping animation.